# Multiple Rows to a single row

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am getting multiple row from database but i want to get multiple row in a single row.

```
var result = db.USER_PRODUCT_INGRED_ASSIGN
               .Where(x => x.AspNetUser.UserName == User.Identity.Name)
               .GroupBy(x => x.PRODUCT.PID).ToList();
```

In this way, I am getting the list of all product that a user buys. now I want to calculate the whole amount of a single product. No matter, How much time it bought I just want a list of all product and if a product buys more than one just calculate the whole price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the total sum per product you need to use aggregate `Sum`. I don't know the name of your price/amount column. But your code should look something like this:

```
db.USER_PRODUCT_INGRED_ASSIGN
               .Where(x => x.AspNetUser.UserName == User.Identity.Name)
               .GroupBy(x => x.PRODUCT.PID)
               .Select(g => new{ PID = g.Key, TotalSum = g.Sum(x => x.PRODUCT.Amount) })
```